# Exclude certain directories and files in pdepend, phpmd, phpcpd, phpcs, phpdoc, phploc

Tags: phpunit, jenkins, phpdoc, php-codebrowser

In my project there are certain directories and certain php files which are very large in size due to which my build is failing and I want to exclude them in my `build.xml`

**Ques1-** Do I have to write the `--ignore="path/filename"` for every php file in the project?

**Ques2-** There are certain files which are not php but `.dat` so should I mention these files in the `--ignore` too?

**Ques3-** Can I specify to exclude files based on their size such that I exclude all the files larger than 500kb?

My current xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="name-of-project" default="build" basedir=".">
  <property name="root.dir" value="${basedir}/.."/>
  <property name="source" value="${root.dir}"/>

 <target name="clean"
         description="Clean up and create artifact directories">
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>

  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit"
         description="Run unit tests using PHPUnit and generates junit.xml and clover.xml">
  <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true">
    <env key="DOCUMENT_ROOT" value="${source}/api"/>
    <env key="MODEL_ROOT" value="${source}/model"/>
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="parallelTasks"
         description="Run the pdepend, phpmd, phpcpd, phpcs, phpdoc and phploc tasks in parallel using a maximum of 2 threads.">
  <parallel threadCount="2">
   <sequential>
    <antcall target="pdepend"/>
    <antcall target="phpmd"/>
   </sequential>
   <antcall target="phpcpd"/>
   <antcall target="phpcs"/>
   <antcall target="phpdoc"/>
   <antcall target="phploc"/>
  </parallel>
 </target>

 <target name="pdepend"
         description="Generate jdepend.xml and software metrics charts using PHP_Depend">
  <exec executable="pdepend">
   <arg value="--jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml" />
   <arg value="--jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg" />
   <arg value="--overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg" />
   <arg value="--ignore=${source}/web" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd"
         description="Generate pmd.xml using PHPMD">
  <exec executable="phpmd">
   <arg path="${source}" />
   <arg value="xml" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml" />
   <arg value="--reportfile" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd.xml" />
   <arg value="--exclude" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/web" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcpd"
         description="Generate pmd-cpd.xml using PHPCPD">
  <exec executable="phpcpd">
   <arg value="--log-pmd" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml" />
   <arg value="--exclude" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/web" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phploc"
         description="Generate phploc.csv">
  <exec executable="phploc">
   <arg value="--log-csv" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
   <arg value="--exclude" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/web" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs"
         description="Generate checkstyle.xml using PHP_CodeSniffer">
  <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
   <arg value="--report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg value="--ignore=${source}/web" /> 
   <arg path="${source}" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpdoc"
         description="Generate API documentation using PHPDocumentor">
  <exec executable="phpdoc">
   <arg value="--directory" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
   <arg value="--target" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/api" />
   <arg value="--ignore" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/web" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcb"
         description="Aggregate tool output with PHP_CodeBrowser">
  <exec executable="phpcb">
   <arg value="--log" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs" />
   <arg value="--source" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
   <arg value="--ignore" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/web" />
   <arg value="--output" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/code-browser" /> 
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="build" depends="clean,parallelTasks,phpunit,phpcb"/>
</project>
```

And I am getting errors like these

```
pdepend:
     [exec] PHP_Depend 0.10.5 by Manuel Pichler

     [exec] Parsing source files:
     [exec] phpcpd 1.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.

     [exec] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /usr/share/pear/PHPCPD/Detector.php on line 115
     [exec] PHP Stack trace:
     [exec] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpcpd:0
     [exec] PHP   2. PHPCPD_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpcpd:51
     [exec] PHP   3. PHPCPD_Detector->copyPasteDetection() /usr/share/pear/PHPCPD/TextUI/Command.php:216
     [exec] PHP   4. token_get_all() /usr/share/pear/PHPCPD/Detector.php:115
     [exec] Result: 255

phploc:
     [exec] phploc 1.6.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

     [exec] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /usr/share/pear/PHPLOC/Analyser.php on line 279
     [exec] PHP Stack trace:
     [exec] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phploc:0
     [exec] PHP   2. PHPLOC_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phploc:51
     [exec] PHP   3. PHPLOC_Analyser->countFiles() /usr/share/pear/PHPLOC/TextUI/Command.php:215
     [exec] PHP   4. PHPLOC_Analyser->countFile() /usr/share/pear/PHPLOC/Analyser.php:170
     [exec] PHP   5. token_get_all() /usr/share/pear/PHPLOC/Analyser.php:279
     [exec] Result: 255
```

What should I do to solve it? If I manually remove the large files from the directory then the build just passes but I want the build to run automatically checking out the code base from svn which will have these large files.

**Ques4-** Can I configure my checkout in such a way that these files dont get checked out?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For every target you can use fileset property or add exclude directories manually

```
<target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
    <exec executable="phploc">
        <arg value="--log-csv"/>
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv"/>
        <arg value="--exclude"/>
        <arg value="${src}/api/"/>
        <arg value="--exclude"/>
        <arg value="${src}/external/"/>
        <arg path="${src}"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="pdepend"
        description="Calculate software metrics using PHP_Depend">
    <exec executable="pdepend">
        <arg value="--jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml"/>
        <arg value="--jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg"/>
        <arg value="--overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg"/>
        <arg value="--ignore=/dir/one/,/dir/two/"/>
        <arg path="${src}"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
    <exec executable="phpcpd">
        <arg value="--log-pmd"/>
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml"/>
        <arg value="--exclude"/>
        <arg value="${src}/api/"/>
        <arg value="--exclude"/>
        <arg value="${src}/exclude/"/><arg path="${src}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Hope my answer will be helpful for someone.

Comment: in case you need to exclude files (not directories), use the option --names-exclude <names>

Answer (score 1):

> In my project there are certain directories and certain php files
>   which are very large in size due to which my build is failing and I
>   want to exclude them in my build.xml
>
> There are certain files which are not php but .dat so should I mention
>   these files in the --ignore too?

What I'm doing in this case is to make a copy of the needed files, and work from there. Either copy the whole directory and delete certain files, or copy over just the needed files. In the former case, the [`find`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) program would do:

```
cp /my/large/project /tmp/work
find /tmp/work -name "*.dat" -delete
find /tmp/work -size 500k -delete
```

In the latter, I'm using [ant's `<copy>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html):

```
<copy todir="${dir.source.our}" includeEmptyDirs="true">
   <fileset dir="${dir.source}/ext" includes="${glob.source.our}"/>
</copy>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted

You'll have to increase PHP memory size in *php.ini*.
Search for [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) and set the value to something like 512 MB, e.g.

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Comment: you can also use ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'), just put it in a config file and include it.

Comment: The only other course is having the analysis fail. Choose one.